# Adding ngCordova Plugin using Intel XDK

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

Can someone please mention the *basic steps* involved in **adding ngCordova plugins using Intel XDK for an Ionic Project**?

Is it possible to do it *without relying on CLI*?

I got a hint of adding third-party plugins on reading Intel XDK docs but not sure how it works.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review this doc page > https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/xdkdocs#517452

In essence, a Cordova plugin is a third-party JavaScript API that you add to your app. It uses the Cordova bridge mechanism to communicate with native code that supports that 3rd-party API. Adding the plugin to your project provides access to that JavaScript API, but you still have to write the code in your app that takes advantage of that API (in other words, including the plugin is like adding a JavaScript library).

Note that once you add a 3rd-party plugin, the only way to test it, with today's edition of the XDK, is to build it and test your built app. We do not currently have a mechanism that allows you to test code that uses a 3rd-party plugin directly within the XDK.

Comment: Thank you! :) Do you know where to find value that should be entered for **Plugin ID** on "import Plugin" page? And, Can you please provide a working sample of controller/view code?

Comment: The plugin ID can be found in the plugin.xml file.